# presenting passbook immediately after creating the file: timing issue

Tags: ios

I am creating a passbook on a server via php script and like to present it immediately in my app. Sometimes the passbook can't be shown, because the php script has not finished writing the file, while the code goes on trying to read the passbook.

Here my code:

```
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://adress/passbook/makePassbook.php"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLConnection *myConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if (myConnection) {
        // Show Passbook
               ....
        NSData *passData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlAdress];
        NSError* error = nil;
        PKPass *newPass = [[PKPass alloc] initWithData:passData
                                         error:&error];
       if (error!=nil) {
           // Show error message
       }

       PKAddPassesViewController *addController =
       [[PKAddPassesViewController alloc] initWithPass:newPass];

       addController.delegate = self;
       [self presentViewController:addController
                   animated:YES
                 completion:nil];
}
```

what would be a good way to check if the passbook file is finished and ready for the PKAddPassesViewController. I was thinking to pause the app for a second or so, but i assume there should be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posted code creates a connection but doesn't run it.  Then it synchronously makes the request to the web service.  Try running an NSURLConnection asynch...

```
// ...your code to setup the request
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

// change the UI to tell the user that the app is busy

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

    // change the UI back to not busy
    if (!error) {
        NSError *passError;
        PKPass *newPass = [[PKPass alloc] initWithData:data error:&passError];
        // your code continues here...
    }
}];
```